# Troubles with dependency injection

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I am working on an ASP.NET WebAPI using OWIN. To manage the instances of DBContext (Entity Framework), I try to use Ninject. However, when I call a controller, the programm returns an error:

> The controller cannot be created, missing constructor.

Could you tell me what is going wrong here?
My Controller Class:

```
public class Testcontroller
{
    private IApplicationDbContext _context;

    public Testcontroller(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

This is the Ninject-File:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            kernel.Bind<IApplicationDbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
    }        
}
```

Ninject Dependency Scope:

```
public class NinjectDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
{
    IResolutionRoot resolver;

    public NinjectDependencyScope(IResolutionRoot resolver)
    {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (resolver == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has been disposed");

        return resolver.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (resolver == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has been disposed");

        return resolver.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        IDisposable disposable = resolver as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
            disposable.Dispose();

        resolver = null;
    }
}

// This class is the resolver, but it is also the global scope
// so we derive from NinjectScope.
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : NinjectDependencyScope, IDependencyResolver
{
    IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel) : base(kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new NinjectDependencyScope(kernel.BeginBlock());
    }
}
```

The Entity Framework DbContext-Class:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Models.Team> Teams { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    DbSet<Models.Team> Teams { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

I tried to follow this tutorial: http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api

What have I done wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Abstract ApplicationDbContext  into an interface and try to inject that interface. also you may have to change kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();   Regester interface of ApplicationDBContext here.

Comment: Ok, i tried that, but the it could not resolve the problem. I updated the code above. What else could it be?

Comment: `public class Testcontroller
{
    private IApplicationDbContext _context;

    public Testcontroller(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}`

Comment: kernel.Bind<IApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

Comment: You cannot bind a concrete class to itself. It has to be interface. I am not sure abt the syntax for binding in Ninject. But whatever you are doing is wrong.

Comment: kernel.Bind<IApplicationDbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>(); is what i have changed it to. How should the Constructor in the Controller be instead?

Comment: Put some break points in your DependencyResolver and DependencyScope and see it they are getting hit. The controller constructor arguments are not being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there was a serious omission in you controller code, your controller is not inheriting from `ApiController`, as is expected with Web Api

```
public class TestController : ApiController {
    private IApplicationDbContext _context;

    public Testcontroller(IApplicationDbContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added that in, but unfortunately, I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

I tried to set up everything from scratch using this: http://www.alexzaitzev.pro/2014/11/webapi2-owin-and-ninject.html

For some reason, it now works out perfectly fine.
Thank you for your support!